# Remove Virtual Box, but am asked to reinstall

Tags: virtualbox

I want to remove virtual box so I can update, so I used:

```
sudo apt remove virtualbox virtualbox-5.0 virtualbox-4.*
```

but all I get is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package virtualbox-5.1 needs to be reinstalled
```

but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: Do you want to update VirtualBox?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update just VirtualBox you can use `sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade virtualbox`. If you want a newer version than what the 
 Ubuntu repositories have then you can find a repository hosted by the developers of the software. For VirtualBox you can find them [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

Adding them on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS would look like this:

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib'
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then you would update and install the desired version

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1
```

The website I linked also recommends installing dkms to ensure VirtualBox kernel modules keep up to date with the kernel that is installed.

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```